# error message appears in wrong place using jquery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use Laravel, bootstrap and jquery in one page, sadly I'm a newbie to all of them. The problem I've met is the error message displays in wrong place using jquery Validation plugin, in the picture below, the message in wrong place is highlighted. As you can see, each radio is included in a label tag, it's required in Bootstrap CSS. I tried to find out which element the message was inserted after, and I failed. Can anybody tell me which part of the code should be changed to move the error message after all radios and how?

[image: original look]

[image: "submit" button clicked]

[image: the radio part in code]

[image: validation part in code]

Comment: Please cut & paste or type your code into the OP, **do not post screenshots of code**.  It makes it much more difficult for anyone to reproduce your issue because they'll have to re-type all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always seem to have the same problem. You can solve it with the `errorPlacement` parameter.

```
$('form').validate({

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        // Get inputs with this name
        var obj = $('[name="'+element.attr('name')+'"]');

        // Are there multiple?
        if (obj.length > 1) {
            // Add error after whatever the parent element is of the last one
            error.insertAfter(obj.last().parent());
        } else {
            // Default, add error after the input
            error.insertAfter(obj);
        }
    }
});
```

You'll have to figure out how you want to handle it, this is just one way.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PgAyp/